# Bookmarklet to combine portion of current URL with user input (to search Twitter user's tweets)

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I often like to search user tweets for specific mentions of specific topics. I think this could be easily done by having a bookmarklet that would pop-up an alert asking for user input, and append that input into a URL, but *also* include a portion of the current page URL.

For example, if I am on https://www.twitter.com/USERNAME I want to tap a bookmarklet that brings up an alert where I can input a "TERM" and then have the browser go to:

https://twitter.com/search?q=TERM%20(from%3AUSERNAME)&src=typed_query&f=live

I have made simple bookmarklets that go to a URL based on user input, and I have made bookmarklets that automatically redirect based on current URL. But I've never combined these two concepts into one. Clearly my Javascript skill is lacking but I think this type of thing could be very useful in many other similar contexts.

Anyone skillful enough to give it a try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this satisfy what you need?

```
javascript:const term = prompt('Term?'); const username = new URL(location.href).pathname.split("/")[1]; window.location.href = `https://twitter.com/search?q=${term}%20(from%3A${username})&src=typed_query&f=live`;void 0;
```

What it does is basically: ask a prompt to input term, then parse the pathname of the twitter URL to get the username, then redirect to the URL you mentioned.

Comment: Genius! Exactly what I wanted. Not only useful but a great line of code for me to study for my own future uses! Thanks